# Getting a session from its data

Tags: multithreading, delphi, session, datasnap

I have a session for the main thread in my application, and that session has valuable data inside it that I want to access. Usually I simply get the session using the `TDSSessionManager.GetThreadSession` method, but right now I'm having to access this session when *outside of the main thread*.

I thought of maybe getting my session by somehow referencing some of the data inside it, but I have no idea how. **Is there any way for getting a session from something else than the thread you're in?**

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your are using recent Delphi version, you can use **Rtti** to have a reference to it. **TDSSessionManager** implements singleton and that will facilitate your job.

Comment: How recent can the delphi version be? (2010 and later? or even earlier?)

Comment: I'm using Delphi XE2. I'd like a more detailed answer. How exactly would I reference to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your Sessions, using the TDSSessionManager.**Instance**

```
TDSSessionManager.Instance.ForEachSession
  (
    procedure(const Session: TDSSession)
    begin
      if Session.HasData('User') then begin
        Listbox1.AddItem(Session.GetData('User'),Session);
      end;
    end
  );
```